# Xcode: Whitelist rejection Phonegap 2.1 (ExternalHosts added!)

Tags: xcode, cordova, whitelist

I'm rebuilding my phonegap/cordova app around the latest phonegap platform (2.1) and immeditalely ran in to an error.

The somewhat classic ***"ERROR whitelist rejection"*** shows up in the output console once the app is launched. *I have in fact added the ExternalHosts array* into my **info plist** as shown below and I'm sure it has been done correctly. I've tried about 2323434 different variations of my domain such as *.quickcore.se , quickcore.se/app www.quickcore.se, http://quickcore.se, etc name but with no further success.

[image: info plist settings]

So what's going on here? Any idea of how to resolve it? I'm using Xcode 4.5.1

Comment: Bravo for trying 2,323,434 different variations. A simple 10 or so would have been enough to defeat me.

Comment: Thank you for writing it with equal gusto. (Yes, I was pointing out how the question had unhelpful information)

Comment: so how about giving it a shot, genius

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have added `ExternalHosts` key to the wrong file. The entry needs to be in `Cordova.plist` in the Resources folder.

Comment: Thanks so much, it saved me a headache!!